# pbs check how much cpu a job is using / job % cpu usage

Tags: linux, unix, central-processing-unit, cluster, pbs

On a cluster a job is submitted to run on N CPUs. qstat -f doesn't show how much CPU resources the job is using other than the time. How does one check whether 100% of each CPU power is used? It is essential to determining the resources required for the task.

Answer (score 1):

[This documentation](https://www.osc.edu/supercomputing/batch-processing-at-osc/monitoring-and-managing-your-job) gave the solution, use pdsh to see output of 'top' on the node, or use 'all' command if a job is running on multiple nodes.

```
pdsh -j 123456 top -b -n 1 -u usr1234
```